# Updating from Angular 14 to 15 polyfills.ts issue

Tags: angular, angular14, angular15

I have updated my app (angular 14) to (angular 15)

I already perform this commands

```
ng update @angular/core@15 @angular/cli@15 --force
ng update @angular/material@15
```

When I run the app for checking

I got this error

```
Error: polyfills.ts:100:7 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'providers' must be of type '(Provider | EnvironmentProviders)[]', but here has type 'Provider[]'.
```

Any idea what am I missing here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Angular 15, the file `polyfills.ts` is neither generated nor required. You can update your polyfills configurations in the `angular.json` file. But regardless of where you keep your polyfills configurations, just make sure you use a consistent type for your `provider` property as explained in the error you are getting.